# update_attribute is modifying password in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have a User model. I am trying to update a "confirm" attribute from Admin model. But while doing this, all the attributes are passed all over again; and due to the hashing used, the password which is passed again due to this, is getting changed.
I have implemented my model as in the tutorial by Michael Hart, and have used the same hashing technique.

Comment: code from admin controller:


def confirm
@ users = User.find_all_by_confirmed(false)
end

def confirm_user
@ user = User.find(params[:id])
@ user.update_attribute(:confirmed,true)
redirect_to :back 
end

Comment: Edit your question, and add the code, properly formatted, there.

Comment: i dont know how to do it.
is there any way with which you can update only one attribute? without touching any other

Comment: @AmeyaJoshi I've updated the question with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `update_attribute()` use `update_column(:name, value)` method, because `update_attribute` invokes the callback methods which are updating your password.

Answer (score 1):

in the Admin model you can set the attributes wich are accessible by whitelist

```
attr_accessible :username
```

now when POSTed only the :username property of User can be adjusted.

Comment: actually im not posting anything. im simply using the update_attribute method. the password is already mass assignment protected. it is getting changed because of authenticate and encrypt methods in the user model.

Comment: also there is no admin model.

Comment: In my knowledge when using the Edit method it will use an http GET request to get the corresponding object by id, _form will be rendered again and the attributes will be loaded into the form, to save/update this record you will click a submit button wich uses an http POST request to update the attributes, with attr_accesible you can whitelist the attributes wich will be affected by this POST request. That this is a also a way to protect your database from mass assignment has nothing to do with your current issue in my point of view.